# jqGrid dynamic col groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

this is my first question here so i will try to explain myself the best I could.

With ajax and json I am doing a dynamic grid that only has the first and the total columns as fixed. The columns in the middle (lets say months). Are variables between 2-24, 2 per month.
So in java, once I know the amount of moths I create a json object with an array of colNames, another one with an array of colModels.
The fact is that I need to put a group header by 2 columns (1 per month). But the loop that is executing the group heading is not working properly.

```
    var col_names = [];
    var col_model = [];
    var col_group = [];
    var col_index = [];
     $.ajax({url: 'JsonServFactModel.action?'+params,
              success: function(data) {
                col_names = data.names;
                col_model = data.model;
                col_group = data.groups;
                col_index = data.index;
                alert(col_model);
                alert(col_index);
     jQuery('#gridServFactId').jqGrid({
        url:'JsonServFactList.action?'+params,
        datatype:'json',                                            
        mtype:'POST',
        colNames: col_names,
        colModel: col_model,
        jsonReader : {
            root:'gridModelToShow',
            repeatitems:false,
            id:'cdServFact'
        },
        width: 790,
        emptyrecords:'Sin registros',
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,15,20],
        pager: '#gridServFactPager',
        sortname: 'cdServFact',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'asc',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        caption: 'Servicios Facturados',
        height: '100%'
        , onSelectRow : function(row_id){
            var values = jQuery("#gridServFactId").getRowData(row_id);
            showHideEdit(values['cdServFact']);
        }
    });
    $('.ui-jqgrid-title').css('width', '98%');

    //??? no se que hacen ¿¿¿¿¿¿    
    $(".ui-jqgrid-labels").css('font-size','10px');
    $(".ui-pg-table").css('font-size','10px');  
    //Saco los botones genericos de la grilla
    $("#gridServFactId").navGrid('#gridDifConciliaPager',{refresh:false,edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false});
    //Reload de la tabla para el display de los datos cargados
    $('#gridServFactId').trigger('reloadGrid');

    addButtonsToServFactGrid();

    alert(col_index.length);
    alert(col_index);
    for (var i = 0; i < col_index.length; i++) {
        //Do grouping
        jQuery("#gridServFactId").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
              useColSpanStyle: false, 
              groupHeaders:[
                {startColumnName: col_index[i], numberOfColumns: 2,        
                    titleText: col_group[i]}  ]
            });

        }
    }

    });
```

The json objects contain
(imagine them like an array)
    col_names = Descripcion,
Producto1,Remitos1,
Producto2,Remitos2,
Productos Total,Remitos Total

col_model=[{name : 'cdProd' , index: 'mes1', width : 100, align : 'left', hidden : false },
  {name : 'ctServFactMes1', index: 'ctServFactMes1', width : 100, align : 'right', hidden :    false }, 
 {name : 'ctRemitosMes1', index: 'ctRemitosMes1', width : 100, align : 'right', hidden : false },
 {name : 'ctServFactMes2', index: 'ctServFactMes2', width : 100, align : 'right', hidden : false },
  {name : 'ctRemitosMes2', index: 'ctRemitosMes2', width : 100, align : 'right', hidden : false },
  {name : 'ctServFactTotal', width : 100, align : 'right', hidden : false }, 
  {name : 'ctRemitosTotal', width : 100, align : 'right', hidden : false }]

col_index = ctServFactMes1,ctServFactMes2,ctServFactTotal

col_groups = Mes1,Mes2,Totales

The group headers are generating a line for each one, I would post a picture but do not have enough reputation

```
|         |         |        |            headT |
|         | head1            |         |        |
| PRODUCT | prod0   | rem0   | prod1   | rem1   |<br>
```

I think the problem comes with multiple calling of the

```
    jQuery("#gridServFactId").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
         ....
        });
```

is there any way of doing this dinamycally?